# Cant return control from shouldPerformSegue when using UIAlertViewController in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uialertcontroller

I am using below code in **shouldPerformSegue**. I want to stop or continue segue based on whether user selects delete or cancel.

I noticed that segue stops due to the alert. If I remove alert then segue works fine.

Is `shouldPerformSegue` incorrect place to use such validation?

Thanks.

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Confirm Delete", message: "Are you sure?", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

let deletelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Delete", style: UIAlertActionStyle.destructive) { (result : UIAlertAction) -> Void in
            print("Delete")

    if self.selection != nil {    
        if self.selection!.delete() == true { //this is database call
            self.success =  true
        } else {
            self.success =  false
    }
}         
let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel) { (result : UIAlertAction) -> Void in
    print("Cancelled delete")
    self.success =   false
}
alertController.addAction(deletelAction)
alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

return success
```

Comment: You are setting `success` to `true/false` within closures, so you should use callback instead of a `return` method.

Comment: Santosh, I haven't used callbacks so far so need to learn first. Will check out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer thanks to comment by [Paulw11](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3418066/paulw11) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33466275/how-to-execute-button-press-action-before-prepareforsegue-in-ios).

So I deleted unwind segue from Delete bar button and added from View Controller to Exit. And then I call this segue programmatically from delete action method. This worked.

however I noticed that `shouldPerformSegue` was not called. The reason is explained at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26946596/430690) by [nburk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1779113/nburk) that `shouldPerformSegue` will not be called if segue is called programatically. This is really smart of Apple engineers :)